# Dynamic proxy for suspend methods?

Tags: kotlin

This is my interface:

```
interface BlogService {
    suspend fun tag() : JsonObject
}
```

Is it possible to create a dynamic proxy for the suspend method and run coroutine inside?
I can't use "Proxy.newProxyInstance" from jdk because I get a compilation error (suspend function should be run from another suspend function)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. And I think the answer is Yes. Here's what I figured out.

The following interface

```
interface IService {
    suspend fun hello(arg: String): Int
}
```

is compiled into this

```
interface IService {
    fun hello(var1: String, var2: Continuation<Int>) : Any
}
```

after compilation, there's no difference between a normal function and a suspend
function, except that the latter one has an additional argument of type
`Continuation`. Just return `COROUTINE_SUSPENDED` in the delegated
`InvocationHandler.invoke` if you actually want it supended.

Here's an example of creating an ISerivce instance via the java dynamic proxy
facility `Proxy.newProxyInstance`

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy
import kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
import kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics.COROUTINE_SUSPENDED
import kotlin.coroutines.resume

fun getServiceDynamic(): IService {
    val proxy = InvocationHandler { _, method, args ->
        val lastArg = args?.lastOrNull()
        if (lastArg is Continuation<*>) {
            val cont = lastArg as Continuation<Int>
            val argsButLast = args.take(args.size - 1)
            doSomethingWith(method, argsButLast, onComplete = { result: Int ->
                cont.resume(result)
            })
            COROUTINE_SUSPENDED
        } else {
            0
        }
    }
    return Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        proxy.javaClass.classLoader,
        arrayOf(IService::class.java),
        proxy
    ) as IService
}
```

I believe this code snippet is simple enough and self-explaining.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what the "doSomething" function does, and where the "onComplete" function is being called or passed. How do we resume the suspended coroutine?

Comment: I just played with this code, and it seems this will not work when the suspending function throws an error. The JVM wraps this error in an "UndeclaredThrowable" exception, which should then be catched by the caller of the proxy (which is code you don't want to change).